# Resolving HttpRequestBase in MEF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef, mef2

I'm pretty new to MEF, I always used to use autofac, which automatically registers all the "Web Request"-scoped objects in the life time scope of the Request, so you can always resolve HttpRequestBase and similar objects in dependencies.

Is there a way to modify the MEF container registration to be able to resolve this dependency?

```
[Export(typeof(ICustomerContext))]
public class WebCustomerContext : ICustomerContext
{
   private readonly HttpRequestBase request;

   [ImportingConstructor]
   public WebCustomerContext(HttpRequestBase request)
   {
            this.request = request;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get the behavior you want if you export your part using the `NonShared` creation policy. That way, a new instance of the part will be created for each request:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
```

Comment: Really, MEF doesn't create an instance per dependency by default? Let me try and get back to you...

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. I suspect something still needs to be done to register the asp.net context instances with the request life time container, but I'm not sure how